# I need to convert an int variable to double

Tags: java

My friend is trying to make some kind of calculation as a task for class, and he's having some trouble.

The problem is that he gets an input from the user as int (it has to be, it's a part of the task). He is trying to convert it to double in the code below, but this doesn't work. The results are int anyway.

```
double firstSolution = ((b1 * a22 - b2 * a12) / (a11 * a22 - a12 * a21));
double secondSolution = ((b2 * a11 - b1 * a21) / (a11 * a22 - a12 * a21));
```

Comment: Write `((double)b1)` instead of just `b1`; likewise for `b2.` The promotion to `double` will propagate.

Comment: Assuming that the a and b variables are ints, just do a double typecast

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You have to cast one (or both) of the arguments to the division operator to `double`:

```
double firstSolution = (b1 * a22 - b2 * a12) / (double)(a11 * a22 - a12 * a21);
```

Since you are performing the same calculation twice I'd recommend refactoring your code:

```
double determinant = a11 * a22 - a12 * a21;
double firstSolution = (b1 * a22 - b2 * a12) / determinant;
double secondSolution = (b2 * a11 - b1 * a21) / determinant;
```

This works in the same way, but now there is an *implicit* cast to double. This conversion from `int` to `double` is an example of a [widening primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).

Comment: Just pointing the risk here, `b1 * a22 - b2 * a12` would result in a `int`, same as the determinant. Leading to some calculation error since the cast will be done after the operation in `(  )`.

Answer (score 46):

Converting to double can be done by [casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java) an int to a double:

You can convert an int to a double by using this mechanism like so:

```
int i = 3; // i is 3
double d = (double) i; // d = 3.0
```

Alternative (using Java's automatic type recognition):

```
double d = 1.0 * i; // d = 3.0
```

Implementing this in your code would be something like:

```
double firstSolution = ((double)(b1 * a22 - b2 * a12) / (double)(a11 * a22 - a12 * a21));
double secondSolution = ((double)(b2 * a11 - b1 * a21) / (double)(a11 * a22 - a12 * a21));
```

Alternatively you can use a hard-parameter of type double (1.0) to have java to the work for you, like so:

```
double firstSolution = ((1.0 * (b1 * a22 - b2 * a12)) / (1.0 * (a11 * a22 - a12 * a21)));
double secondSolution = ((1.0 * (b2 * a11 - b1 * a21)) / (1.0 * (a11 * a22 - a12 * a21)));
```

Answer (score 13):

I think you should casting variable or use `Integer` class by call out method `doubleValue()`.

Comment: Casting to `double` from `int` is not possible, but `doubleValue ()` helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Either use casting as others have already said, or multiply one of the int variables by `1.0`:

```
double firstSolution = ((1.0* b1 * a22 - b2 * a12) / (a11 * a22 - a12 * a21));
```