# Double.Parse double method in java didn't work

Tags: java

Why can't I use the `parseDouble` method to convert int to double in Java?

I tried to convert int to double with the `parseDouble` method in java, but I got an error. Instead of `parseDouble`, I use newDouble method, I get output. Why didn't the `parseDouble` method work?

Comment: "Why i can't use parseDouble method to convert int to double in java?" - because that's not what it's there for. It's there to parse a *text* representation. To convert an `int` to `double` in Java you don't need a method at all - there's an implicit conversion: `int x = 5; double y = x;`

Comment: from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) you can see that this method accepts a `String` argument and not an `int`, so it cannot be used to convert an `int` (it will be able to convert a `String` with an `int` value, e.g. `Double.parseDouble("123")`, but only because it also is a valid `double` representation)

Answer (score 4):

Note that the declaration of the `Double.parseDouble()` method in Java is as follows.

```
public static double parseDouble(String s)
```

Since the `parseDouble` method accepts a String argument, you cannot pass an `int` value as an argument. If you pass an `int` value for the `parseDouble` method, you will get the `error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to String` exception.

Furthermore, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252903/i-need-to-convert-an-int-variable-to-double) to find out the proper way of converting an `int` to a `double`.