# Why different design for dynamic binding and calling child only method from parent class?

Tags: java, polymorphism, subclass, superclass, dynamic-binding

I know for the case of overriding methods Java follows dynamic binding. But if we call a child only method from the parent reference variable, which is referring to child object, we got compilation error.
**Why java follow this design (i.e. why no dynamic binding in second case)?**

```
class A{
    public void sayHi(){ "Hi from A"; }
}


class B extends A{
    public void sayHi(){ "Hi from B"; 
    public void sayGoodBye(){ "Bye from B"; }
}


main(){
  A a = new B();

  //Works because the sayHi() method is declared in A and overridden in B. In this case
  //the B version will execute, but it can be called even if the variable is declared to
  //be type 'A' because sayHi() is part of type A's API and all subTypes will have
  //that method
  a.sayHi(); 

  //Compile error because 'a' is declared to be of type 'A' which doesn't have the
  //sayGoodBye method as part of its API
  a.sayGoodBye(); 

  // Works as long as the object pointed to by the a variable is an instanceof B. This is
  // because the cast explicitly tells the compiler it is a 'B' instance
  ((B)a).sayGoodBye();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the dynamic dispatch of method invocation could come into action, the code has to go through the compiler. When you invoke a method using a reference of a class `C`, compiler looks out for declaration of that method in that class `C`. Compiler only worries about what the reference type it is. It can only validate a method invocation on that much information. If it can't find the method in class `C` it will give you compiler error.

So, for the invocation:

```
a.sayGoodBye();
```

Since `a` is an reference of class `A`, compiler will look for the method in class `A`, and if it cannot find, it will give compiler error.

Comment: But at runtime it follows dynamic binding.
Means I can say that for the call `a.sayHi()` compile try to find `sayHi()` declaration of `sayHi()` in A and as it exists there, so no error. Then at runtime things are called on the basis of object (i.e. memory address) and there lies C's definition of `sayHi()` so it is called.

And for method `sayGoodbye` as you get the error at compile time (as you explained), there should be no question of which definition is getting called at the runtime.

Comment: @knoxxs. Yeah exactly. There is no question of behaviour at runtime, when the code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

`B` [is a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `A`, but `A` [is not necessarily](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `B`. So `B`'s method cannot be invoked on `A` reference

Comment: but in case of method overriding it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Think it like that: When B extends A; it means

```
B = <All non-private stuff of A> + Its own stuff
```

It means B has all the privilege to use the stuff of A. (Its like A becomes a subset of B)

But A never knew about B here and what B contains; so, it cannot use B's stuff. If someway it is need to force A to behave like B (we use cast) and since here `A is not B`; the casting will fail at runtime.

To know more about Java casting, please read [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java)

Comment: But then why in case of overriding A can access B's method definition?

Comment: I did not get 'overriding A' thing? Could you please add an example of overriding A and accessing B's method? If you are saying about the second case failure in your example, it is because at the compile time, the reference is of Type A; so only the methods of A is visible. If you knew that A is indeed keep a reference on B, you need to tell the compiler by using Casting. Since B is a child of A, any reference on B does not need a casting, because compiler for sure knows that B is an A (and hence it can behave like A).

Comment: See what is get printed when you call `a.sayHi()`.

Comment: This is called runtime binding. Honestly, compiler never knew that it will end us with a B object at runtime. All it knew that the reference is of type A and A has a method called sayHi() .. it is all happy with this. Compiler never knew that there is a class B which is overriding sayHi(); actually it does not care.. it is simply checking if you are calling a method, which belongs to reference type or not. continued....

Comment: Continued from last comment.... Since At runtime, object got changed and it was holding the method (either inherited or overriden); the method got executed. If B would not have overriden the A's sayHi(); it would end up executing A's method.