# retrieve array from hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I'm trying to create a hashmap which has a `String` key and stores an `Integer` array.
While using `hashmap.get()` , I want to retrieve the stored array.
I've used to following code:

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap();
String[] arr=new String[]{"-1","-1","-1","-1"};
hm.put("A", arr);
hm.put("B", arr);
hm.put("C", arr);
hm.put("E", arr);
Set set = hm.entrySet();
Iterator i = set.iterator();
while(i.hasNext()) 
{
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
    System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
    System.out.println(me.getValue());
}
```

The output i'm getting is:

```
D: [Ljava.lang.String;@88d00c6
E: [Ljava.lang.String;@88d00c6
A: [Ljava.lang.String;@88d00c6
B: [Ljava.lang.String;@88d00c6
C: [Ljava.lang.String;@88d00c6
```

Can anyone please help!!

Comment: Check out the `Object#toString()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println` uses the default `toString` method for arrays, which is ugly (some people claim it is the memory address of the array in the virtual machine). Instead, use a utility function or print the array's contents manually.

```
while(i.hasNext()) 
{
    Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry)i.next();
    System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
    String[] value = (String[])me.getValue();
    for(String str:value)
    {
        System.out.println(str+"\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: at String[] value = me.getValue(); it gives an error "cannot convert objects into strings"

Comment: @Mohit: Thanks for pointing that out, fixed now. I just forgot to [cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java).

Answer (score 3):

```
 System.out.println(me.getValue());
```

That each value is an Array. When you print, by default `Object#toString()` method calls and result in that hex string.

Try to use the util method from Arrays class, to print array.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(me.getValue()));
```

Comment: I actually have to print the data stored in the hashmap... the data that i retrieve from the map..Arrays.toString() does not work for objects... me.getValue() is an object

Comment: @Mohit When I said array that mean me.getValue() :)

Answer (score 2):

use `Arrays.toString(me.getValue());` instead, default implementation of array Object's `toString()` doesn't return in pretty format

Comment: Arrays.toString() does not work for objects... me.getValue() is an object

Comment: @Mohit you could use generics so Arrays.toString() will recieve String[]