# return a double value from a Jtable

Tags: java, jtable, row

trying to return a specific cell. the user selects a row and the value is converted to double.
the column is always number 3. this is what I have tried doing so far but i get an error saying cannot convert object to double

```
        numberRow = TOrders.getSelectedRow();
        TOrders.getSelectedRow();
        subCost = TOrders.getModel().getValueAt(numberRow, 3);
```

help required !!!

Comment: Why did you give this a "delete" tag?

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving an Object instead of a double. You'll need to [cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java) it to a Double in order to be able to treat it as such:

```
subCost = (Double) TOrders.getModel().getValueAt(numberRow, 3);
```

Also,

```
TOrders.getSelectedRow();
```

does not do anything useful. You should remove this line.

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double , im now getting this error

Comment: Then the value you are trying to retrieve is not a numeric value. Are you using , or . as separator for real numbers? Using , will indeed yield an exception, using . is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The getValueAt() method of the TableModel interface returns a descendant of Object. Your error message indicates it is a String. So it seems that you should convert the Object reference returned to a String reference with a cast. Then convert that String to a double with Double.parseDouble(). parseDouble will throw a NumberFormatException if the string is not a valid double:

```
try {
    numberRow = TOrders.getSelectedRow();
    String temp = (String) TOrders.getModel().getValueAt(numberRow, 3);
    subCost = Double.parseDouble(temp);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Item in table was not a valid double - "
             + e.getMessage() );
}
```

If you want to deal with currency data, you may want to put it in a BigDecimal. Constructing a BigDecimal with a String that does not contain a valid decimal number throws a NumberFormatException.

```
try {
    numberRow = TOrders.getSelectedRow();
    String temp = (String) TOrders.getModel().getValueAt(numberRow, 3);
    subCost = new BigDecimal(temp);
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
         "Item in table was not a valid decimal number");
}
```