# Selenium-Webdriver-Object declaration

Tags: selenium-webdriver

What is the difference between below two statement?

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

FirefoxDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java).

With `WebDriver` you are explicitly casting new instance of `FirefoxDriver()` as `WebDriver` and same for the `FirefoxDriver`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we want to do cross browser testing. If we use first definition

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Then we can use the same object to run test in chrome or IE-:

```
driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

or

```
driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

But if we use second definition, then we have define another instance-:

```
ChromeDriver driver2= new ChromeDriver();
```

or

```
InternetExplorer driver3= new InternetExplorerDriver();
```