# String from ArrayList to two dimensional array using Scanner

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, int

I'm using Eclipse and I'm trying to take a string:

```
1 2 3 4
```

out of an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

And store each number into a two dimensional array:

```
int size = (int) strings.get(0); // Represents the number of rows
int stringList[][] = new int[size][];

// Store results in a two dimensional array
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    int index = i + 1; 
    String fish = (String) strings.get(index);

    Scanner npt = new Scanner(fish);

    for(int j = 0; npt.hasNext(); j++) {
        size[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(npt.next());
    }
}
```

This is the section that is causing the error:

```
// ERROR: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int
size[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(npt.next());
```

Comment: `size` is an `int`, you can't write `size[i][j]`. The error message is very clear.

Comment: Wow I must be completely out of it, I did not notice that at all. Sorry for wasting you guys time.

Answer (score 1):

`strings` is a [raw type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Let's start by fixing that<sup>1</sup>,

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can use [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) *parse*<sup>2</sup> the `String` to an `int` like

```
int size = Intger.parseInt(strings.get(0));
```

Then there's no need for a *cast* in

```
String fish = (String) strings.get(index);
```

You can use

```
String fish = strings.get(index);
```

etc.

<sup>1 <sub>And program to the [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface.</sub></sup>
<sup>2 <sub>Not [**cast**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java).</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant

```
stringList[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(npt.next());
```

though that wouldn't work either, unless you properly initialize the `stringList` array.

You would have to initialize `stringList[i]` (for each `i`) with something like `stringList[i] = new String[someLength];` but I'm not sure which length you should use.

Comment: Yea, sorry. I didn't notice my error. It's so obvious now, but before you guys pointed it out I didn't see it at all.