# What does long <name> = (long) <expression>; do in Java?

Tags: java, types, int, long-integer

What do `(long)` and `(int)` in the following statements before the expression mean?

```
long years = (long) (minutes / minutesInYear);
int remainingDays = (int) (minutes / 60 / 24) % 365;
```

Comment: it's called casting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java

Comment: Try without casting, and you should get your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(minutes / minutesInYear)` is unclear as to what variable type it will return. If you want it in an int variable, you must write `(int)` before it. This is called "typecasting", and it basically converts one format to another. You'll notice that `int a = 10.5;` doesn't work but `int a = (int) 10.5;` does.

In your example, you want this: `(minutes / minutesInYear)` to be stored in a float. So, to make sure it becomes a float, you typecast it using `(float)`

Comment: That's not true. The returned type will depend on the type of those variables.

Comment: @Snak Ok working on it. Got a bit confused for a minute, but I see you're right.

Comment: No problem, just edit it.

Comment: It is still not very clear since it doesn't necessarily return a double

Comment: @nickwouters Yep, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2):

What you see there is casting from one value type to another.

**EDIT: The reason why this is possible is that you might need it if you are working with generic types or inheritance (see the example) and you can not determine the object type beforehand. For this kind of code though, it is often better to just work with the correct types in the first place and avoid mistakes! (in this case double)**

Since an int has no decimal values, the data stored in the int object will not be the exact value of the calculation (the same for a long)

If you want the exact values, you should look at a double instead.

This also works for non numeric values by the way:

```
Object car = new Car();
Car myNewCar = (Car) car;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The edit--stating that casting exists because generic types are there--is just wrong. Casting has been part of Java from the start. Generic types were introduced in Java 1.5.

Comment: I should have added that it is for inheritance aswell, but it is already difficult enough and i was more interested in giving him a why in the first place. If he really wants he can start looking for its uses. I added the edit because nobody was telling why this kind of thing is/was possible in the first place... I even added an inheritance example

Answer (score 2):

The thing that you are talking about is called casting.

You can cast the expression on the right hand side to the one on the left.

The casting can be done on primitive types and also to classes.

**Casting** means taking an Object of one particular type and “turning it into” another Object type. This process is also called casting a variable.

For more you can read [here.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/class_cast.htm)

In your case you use casting because you are converting a variable of primitive type **double** (which is on the right side) to one of type **int** which is on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Casting object because int is not a long, and long is not an int.

`int i = (int) 10L;` - because 10L is long, and you want it to be int.

Comment: You cast a _value_, not an _object_. Also, consider giving a better example because `10` is already an `int` in Java and although you are illustrating the idea, it might confuse the OP further.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade I cast whatever i want xD
 10L is not int, 10L is long, due to L.

Answer (score 0):

Having a type inside a parentheses usually means casting, not only in Java but also in other languages (for instance, C#).

In the first case, if minutes and minutesInYear are integers, **the operation will produce an integer**. **Then you cast it to a long**, which is the same as an integer but 64 bits instead of 32 (it can store bigger values).

In the second case just happens to be the same, but **you cast it to an integer**, **which is probably redundant** (not necessary) as the result is already an integer.

Nevertheless, if you cast a **non integer value** (float, double) to **an integer value** (byte, short, int, long) it will return the **truncated value**, not the rounded value.