# Iterator missing implemented functionality (java)

Tags: java, iterator

I have class which has an Iterator method ( public Iterator iterator(boolean fromFront) ) and my Iterator method returns a "new DoublyLinkedListIterator()". DoublyLinkedListIterator implements ListIterator which contains the set method. The problem is in my main where my iterator doesn't have access to the set method, Iterator iterator = deque.iterator(true); Nor do I have access to the hasPrevious or previous methods.

Comment: Please post your code also.

Comment: if you are sure that you're calling correct method, you can cast returned iterator to your specific DoublyLinkedListIterator

Comment: Also, what is your question ?

Comment: set the return type to ListIterator instead of Iterator, or cast it in the main

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to expose a ListIterator is to have a `public <T> ListIterator<T> listIterator()` method on your class, as in the standard [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator--) class, so you can use it as:

```
ListIterator literator = deque.listIterator();
```

Note that the builtin `Deque<T>` class does not support `ListIterator`s. The variable name is taken from your sample code, it has a custom type.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have access to the methods in *DoublyLinkedListIterator*, you have to *return* it instead of an Iterator. (Or make a cast before using it).

[How to make a cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java), in case you need it.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to use iterator but want to navigate forward/backward and change the links order, ... to be short every write operation that modify the structure of the list, **you're doing it wrong**.

Go for the while/do-while loop if you have such needs.