# (String) Meaning in Java

Tags: java, string

Decided to edit this question.

(String) refers to casting.

Ex:

```
protected String methodA(Vector X) {
    return (String) X.get(0);
}
```

In this case the get method returns an object, and for the methodA to return a String there needs to be a cast to String. And the cast is done as demonstrated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5289393/1743880?

Comment: If I knew it was a cast I would have searched right away... All I could search for was (String) and that led me nowhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, the `(String)` is a cast to string. Without being into the details, I suppose that the return type of `get` is `Object`, even if the contents are of `String` type. The cast is necessary to match the return type of `method`.

Answer (score 0):

This method returns first element in the `Vector` cast to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

If `X.get(0)` returns an Object but the underlying is String then another way besides `(String) X.get(0)` is to use `X.get(0).toString()`. That might be more familiar.