# how does (int)exp.sample() work in the code?

Tags: java, random, exponentiation, exponential-distribution, cloudsim

```
ExponentialDistribution exp = new ExponentialDistribution(4.0);
        for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++){
            timestamp[i] = (int)exp.sample() + 1+timestamp[i-1];
```

Here timestamp is an array of integers and a random value is assigned to it with above condition. What does (int)exp.sample() does and how it assigns a random value to i?

Comment: No idea. What is `ExponentialDistribution`?

Comment: Apparently it's in apache.commons package: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/ExponentialDistribution.html  The main reason I'm sharing this though is to as an excuse to have a meaningful comment that I can also say: your name just has to be a reference to The Who, right?

Comment: `(int)exp.sample()` calls the method `sample()` on the object referenced by `exp`, then casts the return value to `int`. All ***very*** basic Java stuff. Suggestion: Learn Java.

Comment: And there is nothing in the code that assigns a random value to i.

Comment: Also, one hopes that timestamp[0] has been assigned a value somewhere before the code shown.

Comment: @FredK (int)exp.sample() assigns i the random value and beforehand its assigned value 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ExponentialDistribution API:
http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/ExponentialDistribution.html#sample()

> public double sample()
>
> Generate a random value sampled from this
> distribution. The default implementation uses the inversion method.
>
> Algorithm Description: this implementation uses the Inversion Method
> to generate exponentially distributed random values from uniform
> deviates.

So when you see `(int)exp.sample()`, we are converting it to this random value it selected.
exp is the instance of `ExponentialDistribution(4.0)` we've created, so exp.sample() calls `ExponentialDistribution`'s `sample()` method.

Now for the `(int)`.

Placing an Object type or primitive type in parenthesis (int this case `(int)`) prior to another Object/primitive is called "casting". [Casting variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java)

Pretty much, since `sample()` returns a `double`, but `timestamp` stores `ints`, we need to switch one of their types (they must match), and it's waaaaay easier to change `exp.sample()`'s.

So, all in all, this says "Take the object `exp`, call it's method `sample()`, and then convert that into an `int`".

Comment: That stuff i also went through, but i am not getting how the following output is generated.

Comment: timestamp gives value of timestamp[i] and ran gives  (int)exp.sample(). I want know if there is a particular set of numbers from which ran is generated or it depends upon i in the loop condition?........

timestamp = 9 ran= 8,
timestamp=10 ran=7, 
timestamp = 13 ran=6,
timestamp=26, ran=6,
timestamp=34, ran=3,
timestamp=35, ran=7,
timestamp40ran3
timestamp41ran3
timestamp43ran7
timestamp45ran4
timestamp48ran9
timestamp51ran11
timestamp53ran10
timestamp58ran3
timestamp63ran5
timestamp65ran3
timestamp67ran8
timestamp68ran3
timestamp72ran3

Comment: I don't see a `ran` and what you just commented is 100% illegible to me. But I updated my explanation. If you're after how it grabs the value from `sample()`, it just grabs it from a exponential distribution with a mean of 4. If you want to know even more about how it does it, here's the source code: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/math3/distribution/ExponentialDistribution.html

Comment: @Sjs You neither provided any output nor what the variable `ran` is supposed to be.

Comment: May be i got a bit more complexed. ran is nothing, i just used it to denote the output value of (int)exp.sample(), using println. So after"......", i have just pasted the output the loop generated by printing timestamp[i] and (int)exp.sample(). When it says timestamp = 9 ran= 8, it means when loop runs at  i=0, (int)exp.sample() gave output of 8 and timestamp[i] gave 9.

May be you could pardon a newbie for the illeligibilty.

Comment: I no longer know what you're asking. Each index of `timestamp` is set to a randomly grabbed sample plus 1 plus the value at `timestamp` before this one. So every value is getting bigger. Looks like you're creating a discrete CDF or something like that. Well... I guess not, since your values are greater than 1, but some sort of cumulative function...

Comment: Ohk so 4.0 means it grabs value from exp distribution of mean of 4. That helped. Thanks.
So if i change to 5.0, it will take value from mean of 5 , if i am not wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The class ExponentialDistribution generates a pseudo random number following the [Exponential Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution). It is pseudo because it is not truly random. It is used an equation to generate every single random number you get.

The method exp.sample() returns the next random number in the sequence. Using (int) you get just the integer part of it.