# ClassCastException to insert data from combobox in database

Tags: java, jdbc, classcastexception

I'm trying to insert two fields (priority level that is in a `JCombobox` and his ID that is get according the option selected in the combo) and complete the rest of the fields (all String) to submit all... but i'm getting this Stacktrace:

```
run:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: br.com.jdbc.victor.model.PriorityDetail cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall.btSubmitActionPerformed(FormNewCall.java:349)
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall.access$500(FormNewCall.java:30)
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall$6.actionPerformed(FormNewCall.java:151)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at java.awt.Component.show(Component.java:1671)
    at java.awt.Component.setVisible(Component.java:1623)
    at java.awt.Window.setVisible(Window.java:1014)
    at java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Dialog.java:1005)
    at br.com.jdbc.victor.view.FormNewCall.lambda$main$0(FormNewCall.java:495)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

at these two lines under:

```
private void btSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        try {                                           
            Call call = new Call();
            MySQLDaoManager man = new MySQLDaoManager("root", "", "localhost", "attendances", 3306);  
            java.util.Date date_util = new java.util.Date();
            java.sql.Date date_sql = new java.sql.Date(date_util.getDate());
            java.sql.Time time_sql = new java.sql.Time(date_util.getTime());

            try {
                //ClassCastException at this line above 
                call.setPriority((String) cbPriorityDetail.getSelectedItem());
                //this one is giving SQL Error and it's flagged by the Catch block of the code
                call.setPriorityDetail(Long.parseLong(tfIdPriorityDetail.getText()));
                call.setInitialDate(date_sql);
                call.setInitialTime(time_sql);
                call.setFinalTime(time_sql);

                man.getCallDAO().insert(call);

                if(tfCallId.getText().length() != 0){
                     call.setCallId(Long.parseLong(tfCallId.getText()));
                     man.getCallDAO().update(call);
                }
                if(tfInitialDate.getValue() != null && tfInitialTime.getValue() != null && tfFinalTime.getValue() != null){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Inserted User sucessful!!", "Done", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    btNewActionPerformed(evt);
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Please fill the fields again", "Isn't possible to insert data", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    btNewActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            } catch (DAOException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "MySQL Error", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error to get connection", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

This form works at this way: you choose one item at the `JComboBox` `cbPriorityDetail` between high, medium or low, and the `tfIdPriorityDetail` get the corresponding id according to the selected priority (I already did a function that do it and it's working fine) and fill the next three fields: Initial Date, Initial Time and Final Time... if i comment these two lines that are with error and submit the rest it works fine.
I need help about what is wrong at my code?! I can't able to insert the selected combo item and the generated id at the Calls table that I always facing these errors, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your combobox manages 'PriorityDetail' objects, not Strings. You should cast selected object to 'PriorityDetail' and then get data that you need from it.

```
PriorityDetail pd = (PriorityDetail) cbPriorityDetail.getSelectedItem();
call.setPriority(pd.getTheStringThatYouNeedFromYourModel());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi eltabo!!! i've saw now the message, i've fixed the error here through trial and error i did like that: 
chamado.setPrioridade(cbPrioridadeDetalhe.getSelectedItem().toString()); and under i'm supposed to cast to int to it works... i thought strange i don't know the difference between cast with put the type in parentheses and with .toString(); thanks a lot for the help!!!

Comment: Take a look at these explanations: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java) [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3615721/how-to-use-the-tostring-method-in-java)