# Extend Object and Change Method Parameter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I create ImageViewProduct class which is extending ImageView class so i can store some variables in my ImageViewProduct object. But i can't get the ImageViewProduct's variable inside setOnClickListener method..

**ImageViewProduct class :**

```
public class ImageViewProduct extends ImageView {
    boolean toUpload = false;

    public ImageViewProduct(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setToUpload(boolean toUpload) {
        this.toUpload = toUpload;
    }

    public boolean isToUpload() {
        return toUpload;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity class :**

```
ImageViewProduct ivProduct = new ImageViewProduct(this);
ivProduct.setToUpload(true)
ivProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        Log.i("zihad", "is to upload : "+v.isToUpload());
    }
};
```

The log inside onClickListener is error `cannot resolve method 'isToUpload()'`. I've try to change the `onClick(final View v)` to `onClick(final ImageViewProduct v)` but error. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only ever apply this to an `ImageViewProduct` then you could cast `v` to an `ImageViewProduct`.

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
    ImageViewProduct productView = (ImageViewProduct) v;
    Log.i("zihad", "is to upload : "+productView.isToUpload());
}
```

[More info on casting at this QnA.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Log.i("zihad", "is to upload : "+v.isToUpload());
```

to

```
Log.i("zihad", "is to upload : "+ivProduct .isToUpload());
```

v is the variable of View. isToUpload is a method of ivProduct class