# Casting double to int using (int)

Tags: java, casting

I am a beginner and I have searched and search and cannot find the answer to this question. I understand that `int test = (int) (5.4);` is casting a double to an int but what I do not understand is what `(int)` is. It does not seem to be written as a method or a class. It is written in a unique way that I have not seen yet and I am attempting to understand why this statement works in Java. I would have expected something like `int test = Math.int(5.4)`. I do not understand why this statement works. I hope this make sense.

Comment: Its a cast. It basically molds the object into that datatype if it can. Works with most types

Comment: (int) is named **casting**, you can put there any primitive or DataType, like: (double)foo; or (MyCar)fooIVehicle...

Comment: Some more information over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "casting operator". It has its own special syntax in the Java language (i.e. it is not a method call).

It works with Objects, too:

```
 BigInteger n = (BigInteger) session.getAttribute("a number");
```

It is used for two things:

- Conversions between the different number types
- Telling the compiler that a given object has a more specific type (*) than the compiler can infer. This will be checked at runtime, and if it fails, you will get a `ClassCastException`. The compiler will also check if the cast is completely impossible, and reject it at compile-time if that is the case.

(*) or even a less specific type

Comment: Note that you can also upcast, i.e. make the declared type "less specific". This is, however, used more rarely.

Comment: @zero_cool: That's true. That can be used to influence method dispatch based on declared parameter types, for example.

Comment: When you used the words "casting operator" it clicked in my brain. Thank you ALL for spending the time and effort to help this beginner. I am not sure if I should comment on each answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple casting `double` to `int`. This is the syntax supported by java. You will come across similar kind of syntax when objects are converted to a particular class like this:

`(ClassName) objectVariable...`

You may use wrapper classes though such Integer, Float and can user their methods to perform casting as well.

Answer (score 0):

Java allows [casting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) and that is what (int)(5.4) does!
so when you cast you tell the compiler that you need a type conversion 
those conversions must not necessarily be related to primitives, you can basically use any other valid DataType

Answer (score 0):

**What is Casting in Java?**

Well, all casting really means is taking an Object of one particular type and “turning it into” another Object type. This process is called casting a variable.

**What are the Rules behind Casting Variables?**
If you are going to cast a variable, you’re most likely doing what’s known as a downcast. This means that you’re taking the Object and casting it into a more “specific” type of Object. Here’s an example:

```
Object aSentenceObject = "This is a regular sentence";
String aSentenceString = (String)aSentenceObject;
```

You see what we’ve done here? Since the type Object is a very broad type for a variable, we are “downcasting” the variable to be a `String` type. Now, the question is, is this legal? Well, you can see that the value stored in the `aSentenceObject` is just a plain old `String`, so this cast is perfectly legal. Let’s look at the reverse scenario, an “upcast”:

```
String aSentenceString = "This is just another regular sentence";
Object aSentenceObject = (Object)aSentenceString;
```

Here we are taking a variable with a more specific type (String) and casting it to a variable type that’s more generic (Object). This is also legal, and really, it is always legal to upcast.

**[Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)**

19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the *widening primitive conversions*:

- byte to short, int, long, float, or double
- short to int, long, float, or double
- char to int, long, float, or double
- int to long, float, or double
- long to float or double
- float to double

**[Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)**

22 specific conversions on primitive types are called the narrowing primitive conversions:

- short to byte or char
- char to byte or short
- int to byte, short, or char
- long to byte, short, char, or int
- float to byte, short, char, int, or long
- double to byte, short, char, int, long, or float

A narrowing primitive conversion may lose information about the overall magnitude of a numeric value and may also lose precision and range.