# How do I correctly generate a dynamic proxy class that's based on the right class?

Tags: java, generics, casting, dynamic-proxy

I have an interface defined as follows:

```
public interface Cache {
}
```

Then an abstract class implementing the above:

```
public abstract class AbstractCache implements Cache {
}
```

Then a concrete class inheriting from above:

```
public class RealTimeCache extends AbstractCache {
}
```

Then another class defined as follows:

```
public class CacheProbe {
    public static <T> T probe(T base) {
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
                base.getClass().getClassLoader(),
                new Class[]{Cache.class},
                new MethodCountInvocationHandler(base) // I am not mentioning this class as it's irrelevant
        );
    }
}
```

I have a class as follows which is using all of the above:

```
public class CacheLoader<T extends Cache> {
    public T load() {
        T result = getResult(...);
        CacheProbe x = new CacheProbe(result);
        return x.probe();
    }
}
```

Lastly, the lines causing the issue (located outside above classes):

```
final CacheLoader<RealTimeCache> cacheLoader = getNewLoader(); //Method of this method is irrelevant and unchangeable
RealTimeCache x = cacheLoader.load(); //This is the line which is causing a runtime issue
```

Problem is, at run time the following exception is thrown at the last line mentioned above:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57 cannot be cast to RealTimeCache
```

However I don't see how this is possible because the dynamic proxy class generated is based on `Cache`.

How do I fix this ?

***Please note that I can only change `CacheProbe` class in order to fix this. `Cache`, `AbstractCache`, `RealTimeCache`, `CacheLoader` and those last two lines are unchangeable.***

Comment: Do RealTimeCache implements Cache?

Comment: It extends AbstractCache, which in turn implements Cache

Comment: Anyhow you are trying to cast Cache to a more specific class, you have to use something such: new Class[]{RealTimeCache.class} on newInstance method. Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html

OR: Use Cache x = cacheLoader.load() since it will return a Cache

Comment: `Proxy.newProxyInstance` takes an interface based on which it generates a dynamic proxy class, so I cannot provide `RealTimeCache`

Comment: So try: RealTimeCache x = (RealTimeCache) (Cache) cacheLoader.load(); since you are downcasting cache

Comment: I cannot change those two lines. I only have control over the `CacheProbe` class, and so can only change that unfortunately.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos, you cannot successfully cast a reference to a type that is not its own class or a supertype of that class.  Attempting to do so would provoke the same `ClassCastException` at runtime that the OP already receives.

Comment: @JohnBollinger yeah.. i just trying to simulate it efficiently

Comment: Possibly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java. As I said under [your question about this yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51092082/how-to-use-parent-interface-return-type-when-using-extends), you need to actually change `CacheLoader`. There's no way to magically get an instance of `RealTimeCache` from the `probe` method, unless you do something like pass it a `Class<T>`. (Except in this case, since you're making a proxy, it's actually *impossible* to get an instance of `RealTimeCache`, because it's not an interface.)

Answer (score 1):

> However I don't see how this is possible because the dynamic proxy class generated is based on `Cache`.

Yes, the docs for `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` say

> `Proxy` provides static methods for creating dynamic proxy classes and instances, and **it is also the superclass of all dynamic proxy classes created by those methods**.

(emphasis added)

Thus, you cannot use `Proxy` to create (an instance of) a subclass of an arbitrary class of your choice.

> How do I fix this ?

You can create an ordinary subclass of `RealTimeCache`, and return an instance of that.  `Proxy` is meant primarily to serve for interfaces that are not known until runtime, and in that case the only way to interact with them anyway is the interface type.  That's not your scenario.

If necessary, you can implement such a subclass in terms of a `MethodCountInvocationHandler`, just as your proxy class uses, but I'm sure it would be easier to implement whatever tooling that is supposed to provide directly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Can you provide a code sample of what you meant in terms of the solution ?

Comment: I'm sorry, @Ahmad, but I don't follow what you hope to see demonstrated with an example.  Once we take out `Proxy`, everything else in your question is very abstract.