# How to override Java's restrictions for objects

Tags: java, object

I am given an instance of the object class (String, int, double, or boolean) from a database. I need to write a method that can compare this object to something else (String, int, double, or boolean) using binary operators (e.g. <=, !=, >, etc.). I will only run this method if the two objects are of the same type. My method looks like

```
    public boolean comparison(Object a, Object b, String operator) {
         int result = a.compareTo(b);
         String a2 = a.getClass().getName();
         //followed by if/else if blocks to return true or false 
         //depending on operator and result
    }
```

I have designed the if/else if blocks to ensure that no binary operator will be used for incompatible types (e.g. >= for a String object). The problem is that I get a "can't find symbol error" when I try to compile because the object class doesn't have a compareTo() method. If this was python, there wouldn't actually be any issue because I would never be putting anything into the comparison function that didn't have a compareTo() method. However, because of java's formatting I'm forced to declare the input as 'Object' because I can't say specifically what type of object I have to compare at a given moment.

Is there some way I could override Java's restrictions and force it to trust me that Object a will always have a compareTo() method? Because right now, it seems like I'm going to have to downcast the objects into Strings, ints, doubles, or booleans, and then write 4 different new comparison functions for each data type.

Comment: I posted my own solution. There's a two day period before I can accept it. I'll accept it then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Casting variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java)

The top answer summarizes what I wanted to do. The code successfully compiled when I said

```
int result;
if (a instanceof Comparable && b instanceof Comparable) {
   result = ((Comparable) a).compareTo((Comparable) b);
}
```

I haven't tested it, but fantaghirocco's solution also seems like it could work.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `compareTo` method is declared in the [`java.lang.Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, the usage of [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) can constrain your `a` and `b` arguments in order to accept only objects which implement the interface itself.
You can check the `operator` parameter in order to affect the boolean result.
If you wish, the usage of an `enum` value helps to avoid string mismatching.
For brevity, the code below doesn't take in account `null` values.

```
enum Operator {
    GREATER_OR_EQUALS,
    LESS_OR_EQUALS
}

public <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean comparison(T a, T b, Operator operator) {
    int test = a.compareTo(b);
    switch(operator) {
        case GREATER_OR_EQUALS:
            return test >= 0;
        default:
            return test <= 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Java way is to first use the `instanceof` operator to then cast to an appropriate class:

```
if (a instanceof String && b instanceof String) {
  String aAsString = (String) a;
  int comparisonResult = a.compareTo(b);
```

`compareTo()` gives you a negative result if `a < b`, `0` when `a == b` and a positive result if `a > b`. So alone that int result tells you enough to decide what your potential comparison operations should result in. The numeric types `int`/`Integer`, ... have similar methods.

Of course this only works if your assumptions are really correct and the object is really a `String` or `Boolean`. And please note that `boolean` and `Boolean` are two somehow different types!