# Why do i need to do a cast to a specific reference in a object array?

Tags: java, compilation

To reference a specific object inside an Array, i need to cast int to it's type or the compiler do not accept, why do i need this casting?

Exemple:

```
Person[] people = Person[5];            //Generic Array of specific objects

Employee employee1 = new Employee();    //Employee class extends Person
Manager manager1 = new Manager();       //Manager class extends Person

people[0] = employee1;
people[1] = manager1;


Person ref = people[0];                //OK! it can compile
Employee ref2 = people[1];               //Do not compile
Employee ref2 = (Employee) people[1];      //OK! it can compile
```

Why do the cast is necessary?

Comment: Because `people` type is `Person` -> `Person[] people = Person[5];` Compiler don't know `Employee extends Person` and you need to say it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java there is a concept of `upcasting` and `downcasting`. Upcasting means casting to supertype whereas, downcasting means casting to a subtype.

Whenever there is an `Is-A` relationship you can do upcasting without any harm. But it is downcasting which needs to be taken care of.

For example You have `People array` and since both `Employee` and `Manager` classes `extends` `People` so People array can store both of these. Now when you do `Employee ref2 = people[1];` compiler doesn't know that is it actually Employee as there is equal probability that in can be Manager as Manager class also extends People . So you need to explicitly provide a cast which tells compiler that you know what you are doing and no need to give any compile error. But if there is any issue at runtime then a `ClassCastException` will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

It is not compiled without casting since `people[1]` is not known to the compiler to be an `Employee`.

From [Java tutorial. **Casting Objects**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

> We can *tell* the compiler that we promise to assign `Employee` to `people[1]` by **explicit casting**.
>
> This cast inserts a runtime check that `people[1]` is assigned a `Employee` so that the compiler can safely assume that `people[1]` is a `Employee`. If `people[1]` is not a `Employee` at runtime, an exception will be thrown.

See more [Casting variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Type of variable `people` is `Person`. `Person[] people = Person[5];` (`type[] people = new instance` - instance could also be child which extends `type`).

Here `Employee ref2 = people[1];` compiler see `people` as `Person` and you need to say at compiler it also can be `Employee`(cause `Employee` extends `Person`) by casting.

You can read more, about this subject, here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-casting

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an **Employee** ref and you try to instantiate it with a value with the type **Person**.

**Employee** is a **Person**, but a **Person** is not necessarily an **Employee**.
Correct me, if I'm wrong.