# Cannot cast class java.lang.Integer to class java.lang.String

Tags: java, exception, abstract-class

```
    public int compareTo(ListItem item) {
        if(item!=null) {
            return ((String) super.getValue()).compareTo((String) item.getValue());
        }
```

My program is based on the Abstract class concept.

How can I resolve this 
`java.lang.ClassCastException:` in my program?

Comment: Integer is not a string

Comment: `String intAsString = Integer.toString(someInt);`

Comment: return ("" + super.getValue()).compareTo("" +  item.getValue());

Comment: Thank you. It's working. Could you tell me why here we are using an empty string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Casting in Java doesn't magically convert data from one type to another.  Rather, it tells Java that the object stored in a variable actually **is** some other type, which is useful when dealing with inheritance or interfaces.  See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java) for more details.

In this case, the value you get from `item.getValue()` is an Integer.  Trying to cast to a String does not, and can not, work, because *it's not a String*.  It really is an Integer, and trying to call String methods on it won't work.

As others have mentioned, you can convert the Integer to a String using `Integer.toString(someInteger)`.  However, since you're doing a comparison, you should probably just compare the values as Integers.

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation.

Comment: Integer.parseInt() converts a String to an Integer not an Integer to a String.

Comment: @ChadNC Good catch!  Not sure how I reversed that, but it's fixed now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You should use a method such as `parseInt()`

For example:

```
int xInteger = Integer.parseInt(someString);
```

The reason you receive the exception you do is because there is no parent to child relationship between the Integer class and the String class.