# What do round brackets with variable types in java mean?

Tags: java, brackets

I have found this code:

```
Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext(){
  String element = (String) iterator.next();
}
```

What do round brackets in `(String)` mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting variables in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289393/casting-variables-in-java)

Comment: It tells the compiler that object return from iterator.next() will be of type String object, also called typecasting. However in case method returns a different object then class cast exception will be throw at the runtime.

Comment: If that code were updated to use generics properly, the casting would be unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, **Jordan**, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's type conversion (casting).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion

Object returned from iterator.next() is casted to String type.